# Spaces get converted to underscore after a POST request

Tags: php, post, axios

I have some trouble with my Axios POST request.
In fact, the value for my textarea (let's take an example: "Test message") still be "Test message" during the Axios request, but when I `echo $_POST['message']`, PHP returns "Test_message".

Can someone help me?

My form:

```
<form id="post_publication">
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="'. $user_id .'">
    <input type="textarea" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```

My axios request

```
axios.post(
    "/sendMessage.php",
    JSON.stringify({
      message: message,
      user_id: user_id,
    })
  );
```

My php

```
$data = json_decode(array_keys($_POST)[0], true);
echo $data['message']; //returns "Test_message"
```

Comment: use `str_replace()` function to remove **"** `str_replace( '"', $data['message]);`

Comment: You are not sending a _proper_ AJAX request there in the first place. (If you did, then PHP would not populate $_POST in the first place.) And `array_keys($_POST)[0]` would not make any sense to begin with either, if you actually send proper JSON.

Comment: Alright, thanks, problem solved